# There was no endpoint listening at only works when running C# ASP.NET locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, https, wsdl

I have an asp.net C# web application.  I've added a Service Reference to an internet hosted API (wsdl file)

When I run the site locally using visual studio and execute my API call I get the response back as desired.

When I publish the application to one of my web servers, then load the app via the server URL doing the exact same thing the API call fails, reporting the following:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://sprintr.home.mendix.com/ws/StoriesAPI that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 3.126.216.110:443

I tried a few different suggestions including

- Setting the openTimeout, receiveTimout on the basicHttpBindings in my web.config
- Add default proxy enabled = false to my web config

The only thing that I can see is to get it working locally I have to include the following line of code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

If I don't include that line locally it fails and I get:

> An error occurred while making the HHTP request to https://sprintr.home.mendix.com/ws/StoriesAPI.  This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.sys in the HTTPS case.  This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security bindings between the client and server.

Can anyone give me some direction/assistance on this?

Thanks,

Comment: That sounds like your web server is blocked getting to that url.  Can you logon to your web server and test that you can get to that url manually from there?

Comment: it's likely that your web application doesn't match the requirements of the webservice in terms of the security. By adding this line you force particular TLS settings which are accepted. You should check what security standards are required on the WS side and see if you provide everything you need in the httpclient, possibly some headers are missing